# wrong number of arguments from Gmail API when requesting list_user_threads

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail-api

I am successfully authenticating with the API, as I can request messages, add labels, etc. However, when trying to use `list_user_threads` I am clearly misunderstanding the API.

See the method here:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FGmailV1%2FGmailService%3Alist_user_threads

When I execute my code:

```
gmail = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
gmail.authorization = current_user.token.fresh_token
threads = gmail.list_user_threads('me', false, ['Label_69'])
```

I get:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)
```

Any help with understanding how I am misreading the code and passing the arguments incorrectly is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document says it takes one obligatory argument, and several optional keywords arguments. However, you are passing three ordinary arguments, just as the error message says.

Comment: Thank you! `gmail.list_user_threads('me', "include_spam_trash": false, "label_ids": ['Label_69'])` is the fix I needed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you say, "Document says it takes one obligatory argument, and several optional keyword arguments", how do you infer that from the documentation?

Comment: It is not inferring. You can say for sure. (Keyword) arguments without a default value are obligatory. Those with a default value are optional.